# How to add a mesh to each vertex (30k vertices) so can import into UE4

Tags: vertices

I want to import a set of vertices into UE4 but am unable to do so since it lacks any mesh data. Is it possible to convert the 30k vertices into having meshes at each vertex so they are visible and can be imported? e.g. adding a small sphere or cube for each vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a **Skin Modifier**

I created some vertices to test:
[image: original]

Then I added a skin modifier from the modifiers tab:

[image: modifier]

I then got this result, which I think is what you want:

[image: after]

When you are happy with the result, you should be sure to apply the modifier using the apply button in the modifiers tab to actually create the mesh data.

If the squares are the wrong size, go into edit mode, select all the vertices, and press `Ctrl + A` to resize the cubes.

I hope that helps!